# How to solve simplesaml exception missing or invalid password option in config?

Tags: php, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

```
SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION

Backtrace:
1 www/_include.php:17 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: SimpleSAML\Error\Exception: Missing or invalid password option in config.
Backtrace:
7 modules/fabricModule/lib/Auth/Source/fabricAuth.php:29 (SimpleSAML\Module\fabricModule\Auth\Source\fabricAuth::__construct)
6 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:336 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::parseAuthSource)
5 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:381 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::getById)
4 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:68 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::getAuthSource)
3 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:168 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::login)
2 modules/core/www/authenticate.php:38 (require)
1 lib/SimpleSAML/Module.php:266 (SimpleSAML\Module::process)
0 www/module.php:10 (N/A)
```

I am trying to connect my simplesamlphp with MySQL database. I am just retrieving a username and password from the database. I created a custom authentication module for this. My main objective is to create a custom authentication module. I followed [SimpleSAMLphp custom auth](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.19/simplesamlphp-customauth.html) documentation. Here is my code:

```
<?php
  namespace SimpleSAML\Module\fabricModule\Auth\Source;
  use Exception;

  class fabricAuth extends \SimpleSAML\Module\core\Auth\UserPassBase {

    /* The database DSN.
       * See the documentation for the various database drivers for information about the syntax:
       *     http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php
       */
    private $dsn;
    // The database username, password & option
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $options;

    public function __construct($info, $config){
        parent::__construct($info, $config);

        if(!is_string($config['dsn'])){
            throw new \SimpleSAML\Error\Exception('Missing or invalid dsn option in config.');
        }
        $this->dsn = $config['dsn'];
        if(!is_string($config['username'])){
            throw new \SimpleSAML\Error\Exception('Missing or invalid username option in config.');
        }
        $this->username = $config['username'];
        if(!is_string($config['passwword'])){
            throw new \SimpleSAML\Error\Exception('Missing or invalid password option in config.'); 
        }
        $this->password = $config['password'];
        if((isset($config['options']))){
            if(!is_array($config['options'])){
                throw new \SimpleSAML\Error\Exception('Missing or invalid options option in config.');
            }
            $this->options = $config['options'];
        }
    }
     /**
       * A helper function for validating a password hash.
       *
       * In this example we check a SSHA-password, where the database
       * contains a base64 encoded byte string, where the first 20 bytes
       * from the byte string is the SHA1 sum, and the remaining bytes is
       * the salt.
       */
    private function checkPassword($passwordHash, $password){
        $passwordHash = base64_decode($passwordHash);
        $digest = substr($passwordHash, 0, 20);
        $salt = substr($passwordHash, 20);

        $checkDigest = sha1($password, $salt, TRUE);
        return $digest === $checkDigest;
    }

    protected function login($username, $password){
        // Connect to the database
        $db = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        /* Ensure that we are operating with UTF-8 encoding.
           * This command is for MySQL. Other databases may need different commands.
           */
        $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        /* With PDO we use prepared statements. This saves us from having to escape
            * the username in the database query.
            */
        $st = $db->prepare('SELECT username, password_hash, full_name FROM userdb WHERE username=:username');

        if(!$st->execute(['username'=>$username])){
            throw new \SimpleSAML\Error\Exception('Failed to query database for user.');
        }

        // Retrieve the row from the database.
        $row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!row){
            // user not found
            SimpleSAML\Logger::warning('fabricAuth: Could not find user ' . var_export($username, TRUE) . '.');
            throw new \SimpleSAML\Error\Exception('Failed to query database for user.');
        }

        // check the password
        if(!$this->checkPassword($row['password_hash'], $password)){
            // invalid password
            SimpleSAML\Logger::warning('fabricAuth: Wrong password for user ' . var_export($username, TRUE) . '.');
            throw new \SimpleSAML\Error\Error('WRONGUSERPASS');
        }

        // Create the attribute array of the user.
        $attributes =[
            'uid'=> [$username],
            'displayName'=>[$row['full_name']],
            'eduPersonAffiliation'=>['member', 'employee'],
        ];
        // return the attributes
        return $attributes;
    }

}
```

Can you please tell me why am I getting this exception?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You spelt password incorrectly in

```
   if(!is_string($config['passwword'])){
```

That likely does not line up with the password setting in `$config`